# Add Favorite page on domain to sidebar

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a site with various albums what users can browse. I want to add a button that adds the album to thier favorite dropdown menu. Basicly creates an entry on the sidebar for the page.

Is there a way that the user clicks on the Favorites star icon and generates or adds it to the sidebar?

Im using AdminLTE 3 btw.

https://jsfiddle.net/a3ys651r/

sidenav.php example for an entry

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav class="mt-2 ">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active" style="background-color: cadetblue">
              <i class="far fa-solid fa-star nav-icon"></i>
              <p>
                Favorites
                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="album1.php" class="nav-link">         
                  <p>Album 1</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
          </div>
```

Thank you!